# Double integral over $x^2+y^2 \le 1$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to calculate the double integral

$\displaystyle \iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1} (\sin x+y+3)\,dA$

Here are my attempts so far:

1) I used polar coordinates

$ x= r \sin(\theta)$

$y= r \cos (\theta)$

where  $\theta \in [0,2 \pi]$ and $r \in [0,1]$ which gives

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \bigg(\sin\big(r \cos(\theta)\big)+ r \sin(\theta)+3 \bigg)r\, dr\, d\theta$

and stuck with fiding antiderivative of the function with respect to r

$ r \sin\big(r \cos(\theta)\big)$

2) I tried to divide the region into parts that

$A \cup B = \{ (x,y) : x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$ where $A=\{ (x,y) : x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ and $x\geq 0 \}$ and $B=\{ (x,y) : x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ and $x <0 \}$ which gives me

$ \quad\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \int _0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \big( \sin x +y+3 \big)\,dy \,dx + \int_{-1}^1 \int _0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \big( \sin x +y+3 \big)\,dy\,dx$

$\displaystyle =\int_{-1}^1 \big( \sqrt{1-x^2} \sin x + \frac{1-x^2}{2}+3 \sqrt{1-x^2} \big)\,dx + \dotsm $

and stuck with finding antiderivative of the function

$\sqrt{1-x^2} \sin x$.

I will be glad to hear any tips. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason not to split this into three separate integrals:
$$\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1} \sin x\;dA+\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1}y\;dA+\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1}3\;dA$$

You can do the third, I think. For the first, note that $\sin x$ is antisymmetric about the $y$-axis; and for the second, note that $y$ is antisymmetric about the $x$-axis. So there is nothing to evaluate!

Answer (score 2):

The integral of a sum is equal to the sum of the integrals of the summands (assuming all exist, and finitely many summands).

$$\iint_{x^2+y^2=1}\sin(x)+y+3\,dA = \iint_{x^2+y^2=1}\sin(x)\,dA + \iint_{x^2+y^2=1}y\,dA + \iint_{x^2+y^2=1}3\,dA$$

Hint: For any odd function $f$ (a function such that $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$), what is $\int_{-c}^cf(x)dx$?